# Ansible: complicated conditions

Tags: python, ansible

I want to write this piece of code in my playbook:

```
- debug:
    msg: hello
  when: '2 in [x*2 for x in range(1, 10)]'
```

But I have an error:

```
The conditional check '2 in [x*2 for x in range(1, 10)]' failed.
The error was: template error while templating string: expected token ',',
got 'for'.
String: {% if 2 in [x*2 for x in range(1, 10)] %} True {% else %} False
```

How can I rewrite it? I want to use generators for complicated conditions with `with_items`. Here is python example:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
>>> 2 in [x*2 for x in range(1, 10)]
True
```

Comment: You can't write arbitrary Python code in Ansible. If you need some complex things, write your custom filter plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The "when" value is jinja2. The documentation links to the supported comparisons ( http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#comparisons )

For your actual example, this syntax is supported:

```
when: '2 in [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]'
```